# Where do I ask about how to write references in a Report and Research paper?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to ask the following question but I don't know on which site I can best ask this:

> I am about to submit my master's thesis and writing a research paper along with it to submit in CHI conference. While writing I got stuck when I had to mention the references. Here, I have few questions for while referencing the material in the report and research paper.
>
> 1. How to add a research paper references in the end of the report as well as in the research paper? Basically I am asking the format of reference. There are so many format and I don't know which one to use.
> 2. How to add a website references in the end of the report and research paper? Again I am asking the format.
> 3. How to mention these references in the paper or report? What I mean by this is how to include these references inside the report and research paper?
>
> I have read couple of papers and I am extremely confused what to use where and how.

Is there a site within the Stack Exchange Network of sites where this question would be on-topic?

Comment: what is this doing here?

Comment: @Pëkka Can you tell me where to ask this question over stackoverflow? I just stumble upon similar question in the meta.stack so I have asked here. Dont know where to put this.

Comment: Probably [academia.se]. Though they will tell you to ask the conference organizers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This question would belong in the [Academia SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/). Please also go through their [help-center](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help) before you post your improved question.

However, you might want to make your question a bit more clear, by explaining what are the norms and formats followed by the conference paper submissions.

The format depends on the conference and also the type of conference.